# Jquery validation, step by step validate on click function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

Trying to get jquery validation plugin work with my step by step form and here is the function i made. It works but only with first step. Any other step or final submit wont work in that case. If anyone could have a look whats wrong with my code i would appreciate the most.

Thank you.

```
function StepByStep(){

 var a = {  
  rules: {
   fieldname1: "required",
   fieldname2: "required",

  }
 }

 var b = {   
  rules: {
   fieldname3:"required"   
  }
 }

 var aStep = $("form").validate(a);
 var bStep = $("form").validate(b);   

 $('input.nextStep').click(function(){ 

  if (aStep.form()) {
   //open step 2 function   
  } 

  return false     
 });

 $('input.submit').click(function(){

  if (bStep.form()) {  
   $('form').submit();  
  }
   return false

 }); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I took this from, but it seems to be what you are looking for:

```
// We could use it like this: the_form.validate().subset('#first-step')
$.validator.prototype.subset = function(container) {
    var ok = true;
    var self = this;
    $(container).find(':input').each(function() {
        if (!self.element($(this))) ok = false;
    });
    return ok;
};
```